# Angularjs get Json from $routeParams

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a controller which will save address data and will change the location (using $location.path("/checkout/"+ $scope.checkOutAddress);)to the next page with the json response as parameter by

```
$routeProvider.when('/checkout/:checkOutAddress', {
    templateUrl : 'partials/checkOut.html',
    controller : 'myController'
});
```

In the checkout controller trying to get the value using the below code

```
mCommerceApp.controller('myController', function($scope,$sessionStorage,$location,$routeParams,MCommerceService) {
$scope.checkOutAddress=$routeParams.checkOutAddress;
console.log($scope.checkOutAddress);
});
```

So now the problem is I am not able to get the json value. It is coming as an object. The browser log displays [object Object]. Any help how to get the $routeparama as json?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to stringify it

```
var json = JSON.stringify($scope.checkOutAddress);
```

but i'm not sure it's the good way to pass data from controller to another, you can use a provider to stock datas.

```
App.provider('Data', function() {

//Properties declaration
this.tosend = '';

//Setters
this.setTosend = function(tosend) {
    this.tosend = tosend;
};

//Getters
this.getTosend = function() {
    return this.tosend;
};
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am new to angularjs so not aware of providers. Can you explain more specifically?

Comment: i personally use it as an object, or a data stocker, you have much more informations in the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers